# Error while using libsoup

Tags: c, linux, open-source, network-programming, client

I am writing a client using libsoup APIs.
I have done the following.

```
session = soup_session_sync_new();

msg =  soup_message_new("GET","http://www.google.com"); 

status = soup_session_send_message(session,msg);`
```

However now i am getting the following error code in status. I print the reason phrase and it says the `status= 4 , msg->reason_phrase = Cannot connect to destination`

How do i resolve this issue?

Comment: status = 4 means? I think you should look for information from libsoup. I believe the error should mean something.

Comment: This is the return value from the api. Status is unsigned int. The problem is there is no proper documentation of error codes.
I am suspecting its got to do something with network configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was i use a proxy server to connect to internet. Hence i needed to set the session object property of SOUP_SESSION_PROXY_URI  with the proxy-sever:port value.
It works fine now. Time to test POST method now.

Comment: Plus one. I am having the same problem. Coudl you please post the working code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code seems perfectly alright. Just try changing google.com to some other simpler site, may be gnu.org, and retry the code.

Comment: I changed it to gnu.org. I get the same return value. I am running ubuntu on vmware. Does it have to do with my network configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Running the commands as **sudo** worked for me.